# Modifying width in dev tool doesn't trigger resize event

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j.fn.portionHeight = function(ratio){
    var width = j(this).width();
    var height = Math.floor(width*ratio);
    j(this).height(height);
}

function initAndResize(){
    j('.square').portionHeight(1);
}

j(document).ready(function(){
    initAndResize();
    j('.square').resize(function(){
        initAndResize();
        console.log('changed');
    })
});
```

I am using javascript to keep a DIV square. I was adjusting the square's size, changing its width(in percentage) in dev tools to see what size is best. I  hope the height will change accordingly, but it doesn't. I think it is because when changing the width through CSS in dev tools won't trigger the "resize" event, is there any way to overcome this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4og9d7m7/

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4og9d7m7/

Comment: AFAIK only windows have resize event in modern browsers, or does jQuery change this? Notice, that the resize event is never fired in your fiddle.

Comment: That is why I didn't create fiddle in the first place. I was hoping changing width in DEV TOOLS would trigger the event. This can't be demonstrated in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the answer you are looking for perhaps but I thought it might be helpful to share my favorite CSS solution to this problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/sLsxcu9v/1/

Setting the padding-bottom to the same percentage as the div width and the absolutely positioning a div inside to the the full extent of the container is to me a nice fix which may or may not suit your situation.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="square">
        <div class="absolute">
            <h2>I'm still a square</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

div.container{

    width:50%;    

}


div.square {

    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    background-color:red;

}

div.absolute {

    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;

}

h2{ 

    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;

}
```

Comment: Updated with a slightly more versatile version which gives you a bit more freedom to do what ever you want with the container div

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that DOM elements don't have a `resize` event. Only the `window` object has it. However, this is hopefully about to change. There's a new spec promising a `ResizeObserver`. More on this [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver). As of mid 2018, [only Chrome supports it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver), though.